# Clear Html.TextBox() value with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.textbox

I want to clear default value of a textbox with jquery.

```
@Html.TextBox("password", ***@Views.Resource.Password***, new { @class = "cssClass" })
```

Comment: How does the rendered html look like?

Comment: It looks like whatever in @Views.Resource.Password

Comment: This is not what the rendered html looks like, and because I have no experience with asp, I don't know how the result will look like. Ali's solution may work, but you should assign an id to it and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

use this solution :

```
$(function (){

    $("input.cssClass").val('');

});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input.cssClass").val('');

});
```

Comment: I dont want to change css, @Views.Resource.Password shows some default text inside the textbox. When the textbox clicked I want the text to be cleared.

Comment: do you think this code will change your css? it is not correct dude, this code just change the value of the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom html helper to get the id of the texbox:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ClientIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
    }
}
```

The you could say in the jQuery:

```
$("#@(Html.ClientIdFor(m => m.Password))").val("");
```